# How do I format a float as an integer with Struts2 tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, el

It always prints a trailing decimal and 0. I want to convert it to an int. This is what I've tried so far:

```
    <s:iterator var="item" value="results">
        Year: <s:property value="getOnlyField('year').number" /><br/>
        <c:set var="year" value="%{item.getOnlyField('year').number}"/>
        Year: <fmt:formatNumber value="${year}"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was a Double, not a double. This worked:

```
<s:property value="getOnlyField('year').number.intValue()" />
```

This also works for the long way:

```
<s:set var="item" value="%{item}"/>
<jsp:useBean id="item" type="com.google.appengine.api.search.ScoredDocument" />
Year: <%= item.getOnlyField("year").getNumber().intValue() %>
```

in case you had to cast to `(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0.00000}',{orderopenprice})"/>
```

This is what I use to format doubles/floats. For viewing it without decimal you can use :

```
<s:property value="getText('{0,number,#,##0}',{year})"/>
```

More details about getText can be found [here.](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html)

Comment: Thanks! Is getText() something specific to Struts2? It appears as though it would try to call item.getText(), which does not exist. How would Struts know how to interpret that special? What if you DID have item.getText() and wanted to call the object method and not a Struts function?

Comment: It's a struts2 action method, it won't invoke item.getText()